# Is Guava EventBus Google App Engine-friendly?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, guava

GAE restricts new `Thread` instances from being created at runtime. Guava has a nice [`EventBus`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) and I think I'd like to use it in an upcoming GAE project.

But I don't want to even *start* down that road if I'm going to run into any thread-related access restrictions. So I ask: does Guava's `EventBus` utilize thread creation? **Is it GAE-friendly?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you can create an [`AsyncEventBus`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/AsyncEventBus.html) with a [GAE thread factory](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory%28%29):

```
//GAE Thread Factory
ThreadFactory factory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory)
//AsyncEventBus
EventBus eventBus = new AsyncEventBus(executor);
```

See also: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime

Comment: Thanks @SimonC (+1) - Out of curiosity, why can't I just use `EventBus bus = new EventBus()` on GAE? Is there threading going on under the hood?

Comment: As I understand it, if you just instantiate an `EventBus` directly, the events will be fired on the same thread.  This might be OK for your use, but I assumed you were interested in using an asynchronous bus as you mentioned the limitation on creating threads.